# MVC Razor context commutation problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to output a "x3" string with value stored in my model.

`<span>x@Model.Quantity</span>`              output => x@Model.Quantity

doesn't switch correctly to code after @.

The following works correctly:

`<span>*@Model.Quantity</span>`              => *3
`<span>x @Model.Quantity</span>`             => x 3 (but I don't want the space of course)

My actual fix:

`<span>@{<text>x</text>}@Model.Quantity</span>`  => x3

Does the @ commutator needs to follow a word boundary? Is it a bug of the parser?
(my actual testing machine: MVC3 RC2)

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

x@Model.Quantity could be a email address so I think the parser consider that as text. It works if you do:

```
<span>x@(Model.Quantity)</span>
```